# Why is ' 2' > '10'?

Tags: sql, postgresql, collation

Why is ' 2' **with an initial space** bigger than '10'?

```
select ' 2' > '10';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

I tried it with both latin1 and utf8 english collations:

```
                                    List of databases
   Name    |   Owner    | Encoding  |    Collation     |      Ctype       |   Access privileges   
-----------+------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------
 cpn       | cpn        | UTF8      | en_US.UTF-8      | en_US.UTF-8      | 
 teste     | cpn        | LATIN1    | en_US.ISO-8859-1 | en_US.ISO-8859-1 |
```

I know it has to do with the type because when it is cast it works as expected:

```
teste=> select ' 2'::char > '10';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

What exactly is happening here?

**EDIT:**

All the above was done with 8.4.8 in Fedora 13. But I just tested with 9.04 in Centos 6 with the same result:

```
select ' 2' > '10';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

**List of databases**

```
   Name    |   Owner    | Encoding  |  Collation  |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 cpn       | postgres   | UTF8      | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

New Edit:

This is to further confuse:

```
select ' ' > '1';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: Is it different if you take the space out?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: @Jared If I take the space out then it works as expected, that is, '2' is bigger than '10'

Comment: @Vincent I tested with 8.4.8 but I see you tried with 9.0.4 with the same result.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: No, I got the opposite, it returns false in my case, which should be the expected result (char #32 is < than char #49)

Comment: @Vincent Sorry. What is the database collation?

Comment: People, **read** answers before voting.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: Hmm, `\l+` only shows 'c' as the collation.

Comment: I tested with Postgresql 9.0.4 with the collation C, and `' 2' > '10'` returns **false**, as expected. (I deleted my answer where I said this, so I might as well put it in comments.)

Comment: This discussion thread supports that [all UTF-8 collations ignore spaces](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/a-strange-order-by-behavior-td4513038.html). Other similar threads exist, so it seems the issue is that whitespace is ignored in these collations.

Comment: @Dan: you should make that an answer as this is probably the best answer. Note though that the answers to this question have gathered 19 positive and 19 negative votes in total!

Comment: @Dan: I wouldn't say that it ignores spaces. It orders space after numbers and latin letters but spaces may be put before other characters. Some testing is needed.

Comment: @ypercube I cannot test the answer, I don't have a Postgres install within reach. Feel free to steal the link if you want to post an answer.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: your collation is `en-US`.  `C` collation is a neutral, lack of collation (defaults to byte by byte I think).  Please see my answer, since spaces are tried to be removed, but this problem does not apply to equality comparisons (only `>` or `<`), because `=` does a byte-by-byte comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think PostgreSQL automatically tries to figure out the type behind the scenes and in Linux it tries to get rid of the ' ', some of the comparisons are also based on locale.

- Thus, `' 2' > '10'` becomes `'2'>'10'` and the comparison is `'2'>'1'`; they are not equal, so no need to continue with the rest of the string, and `ascii('2')` is greater than `ascii('1')`, so it evaluates to true.
- If it were an equality operation (e.g. ' 22' = '22 ') it would result to false because Postgres does a byte by byte comparison.  This is important because the engine uses two different algorithms when doing comparisons.
- If you specify the type via typecasting, then it won't override the space rules (`' '=>''`).

---

***Also credit goes to:** RhodiumToad and Peerce in #postgresql*

Answer (score 3):

I think this has to do with locale settings.

According to **[PostgreSQL docs: Locale Support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/locale.html)**:

> The locale settings influence the following SQL features:
>
> - **Sort order in queries using ORDER BY on textual data**
> - The ability to use indexes with LIKE clauses
> - The upper, lower, and initcap functions
> - The to_char family of functions