# Postgres Strings comparison peculiarity

Tags: postgresql

Can anybody explain the following contradiction?

```
select 'b.0'<'b00.0';
 ?column?
----------
 t
```

but

```
select 'b.g'<'b00.g';
 ?column?
----------
 f
```

Comment: To elaborate on @Clodoaldo's answer, your language's collation rules likely apply here. It's hard to say exactly what without knowing what language your database is in; show `\l databasename`.

Comment: @Craig Ringer `SHOW lc_collate;` returns `en_US.UTF8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a [collation issue](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html). Try

```
select '.0' < '00', '.9' < '00', '.9' < '00' collate "C";
 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------
 t        | f        | t
```

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo:ICU

Comment: I understand that "C" collation sorts plainly by ASCII, but I wonder what is the logic of the other sort

Comment: @Dikla PostgreSQL uses your operating system's collation support for sorting. What OS are you on? Mac OS X is known to have somewhat borked collations, other platforms tend to be pretty reasonable. I don't know the en_US collation rules off the top of my head so I'm not sure if this result is to be expected or not for en_US.

Comment: @CraigRinger, Interesting, I thought it was OS independent.
I'm working with debian wheezy.

Comment: @Dikla Check the wiki link and also [my not that old question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7053817/131874)

Comment: @Dikla I wish it were, but it turns out to be quite painful to do that well. BTW, compare `echo -e 'b.g\nb00.g' | LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort` with the same command with `LC_ALL=C` - confirms it's OS-level collation rules in play, not Pg.

Comment: Missed the link at first. Thanks!